# constraintlayout views jump to the right after migrate to androidX

Tags: android

In this `constraintlayout` I cant get the TextView to align left.

I have this strange thing that whatever I do the `TextView` jumps to the right.

Here´s a picture:
[image]

I just migrated to androidX maybe that has to to with this dunno..

Here´s the xml layout place advice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pref_category_remote_battery_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:textColor="@color/default_400"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/pref_category_remote_battery_switch_summ"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="30dp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_compat"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:textOn="ON"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:showText="true" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.74722224" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here the build.gradle dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:5.0.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1' } apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' repositories {
    mavenCentral() }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to stay in the left side you can add `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` to your layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layoutDirection="ltr">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="pref_category_remote_battery_title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="pref_category_remote_battery_switch_summ"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/switch_compat"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:showText="true" />

 <android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.74722224" /> 

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So it will stay to the left and look like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you using the exact layout as I posted? And on what phone are you testing this

Comment: Thanks Your using android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout I use the androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout . I dont want to downgrade

Comment: Oh, ye I forgot to mention that the  project that I used for the example was using support version and not androidX. You can change the version to androidX and use the layout.

Comment: Thanks it work you are  MAGICIAN  but when I change 'android:text="pref_category_remote_battery_title"' to 'android:text="@string/pref_category_remote_battery_title" the text jump to the right again, this is so spooky I did not even have a beer :)

Comment: Maybe open a new question about that weird thing happening to you while using string resource. The entire focus would be on this problem and you could get more attention to your question. If my answer was helpful please accept it so other developers with the same problem could use it in the future.

Comment: no wait  I was wrong it only looked like it worked I change the text to like AAA and BBB in the two TextViews and the text end up to the right again. The text `android:text="pref_category_remote_battery_title"` was so long so it looked like it was working

Comment: Feel free to connect me via my [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/tamir-abutbul-10a695178/) and I will try to help you with that when I will return home

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try like below for your (TextView 2)?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/pref_category_remote_battery_switch_summ"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="30dp"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/switch_compat"/>
```

Comment: Thanks not working, this layout is for a custom `androidx.preference.Preference` as you see in the pic, dunno maybe it´s important